# 'Still working' message doesn't disappear while issue drilldown

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube-web

When I make issue drilldown and process an issue changing its status e.g. from `Open` to `Resolved` then the message `Still working` appears above in the window which is normal.

The problem is that the `Still working` message is displayed on the screen for a very long time (a minute or more)! This error occurs independent of the size of the analyzed project.

*A workaround that I'm currently using is to press the `F5` key on the keyboard to refresh the page content. Then, I immediately see my issue with its new status `Resolved`.*

Can the above problem be solved or is it an error in SQ 5.3?

Comment: Do you see a error in the JavaScript console of your browser?

Comment: No, the JavaScript console stays empty.